# Spark creating index in elasticsearch results in OutOfMemoryError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

In a spark job we are creating index in elasticsearch from a file 0f ~120GB. The file is devided into 3830 patitions.After job starts putting data into elasticsearch index, garbage collector messages appear in the elasticsearch logs ending with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

```
[WARN ][monitor.jvm]  [gc][old][209][6] duration [57.6s], collections [1]/[57.9s], total [57.6s]/[3.7m], memory [24.2gb]->[18.7gb]/[24.9gb], all_pools {[young] [8.6mb]->[10.3mb]/[532.5mb]}{[survivor] [66.5mb]->[0b]/[66.5mb]}{[old] [24.2gb]->[18.7gb]/[24.3gb]}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I restarted the elasticsearch nodes and ran job again but, the result was same.

Following are elasticsearch properties in spark config

```
conf.set("es.nodes", "xx.xx.xxx.xx:9200")
conf.set("es.scroll.size", "10000")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
```

We are using Spark 1.6 and elasticsearch 2.0.2. There are three elasticsearch nodes in the cluster each with 25 GB heap space.

Comment: **bootstrap.mlockall: true** Did you configure this in your elasticsearch cluster ?

Comment: 120gb > 75gb so even with an ES replication factor of 0 you don't have enough RAM in your ES cluster. This also greatly depends on how much and what kind of data is in the 120gb you're actually inserting into ES.

Comment: @tricky Yes I did.

Comment: Elasticseach stores the index in disk, so the problem might be on the throughput of pushing document to elastic. How many executors do you use? Try reducing the number of executors.